# .net6 published application won't run as exe but will with dotnet command

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm publishing an app in a normal way (it should be self-contained):

`dotnet publish -c release --output %buildFolder%`

The resulting output is being installed on a machine.

Running like this works:
`dotnet ./product.dll`

... but running the exe fails:
`./product.exe`

The error is produces is:

```
Failed to load the dll from [%pathToApplication%\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from %pathToApplication%\hostfxr.dll failed
  - Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
```

Comment: @HansPassant this is supposed to be a self-contained install ... there are almost 500 files in the build output folder, mainly MS files ... should this require a .net install?

Comment: 0x800700C1 says that it found the file, but it is either damaged or has the wrong bitness.  Surely the latter.  How that went wrong is hard to guess from the question, but likely the bitness of the .exe doesn't match the bitness of the hostfxr.  Do edit it to note the self-contained detail.

Comment: Ok this is great, many thanks @HansPassant, the bitness must be a problem

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from @hanspassant - this was a bitness issue.

My `dotnet publish` did not include an explicit `r` flag and the dependencies were all `AnyCpu` meaning when running as an .exe it was attempting to load as an x64 on a 64-bit machine.

The reason it worked with `dotnet .\product.dll` was that it was using an x86 `hostfxr.dll` which was already present in the build output folder where as with a direct launch of the `.exe` it was not using this file, it seems.